# install windows back

Tags: 12.04, windows

i recently replaced windows with ubuntu,now i want to install windows xp with ubuntu.. my laptop dosent have cd drive so i copyed the files in cd to pen drive . i dont understand how to run the setup.if u know any windows xp iso bootable device creator for linux please post the link

Comment: im still confused on what you want... so you replaced windows with ubuntu and now your hard drive wont work? or are you trying to mount a diffrent hard drive? please be more clear in your question.

Comment: I'm still confused on what you want... So you replaced Windows with Ubuntu and now your hard drive wont work? If you replaced Windows with Ubuntu then all the partitions in the hard disk were deleted. Or are you trying to mount a diffrent hard drive? please edit your question with more information.